# How do I format my GUI using tkinter by using .grid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to use .grid to format my GUI, but it is not doing anything. Here below is my code and my desired layout!

[image]
Here is the code I am using. I am quite new to Python...

I am not sure of other methods of formatting except for .grid so any other options would be great too!

```
from tkinter import *

class PayrollSummary:
    def __init__(pay):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Employee Payroll")

        #Add Frame 1
        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()

        #Add ReadFile Button
        btReadFile = Button(frame1, text = "Read File")
        btReadFile.pack()

        #Add ShowPayroll Button
        btShowPayroll = Button(frame1, text = "Show Payroll")
        btShowPayroll.pack()

        #Add FindEmployee by Name Button
        btFindEmployee = Button(frame1, text = "Find Employee by Name")
        btFindEmployee.pack()

        #Add Highest Radio Button
        rbHigh = Radiobutton(frame1, text = "Highest")
        rbHigh.pack()

        #Add Lowest Radio Button
        rbLow = Radiobutton(frame1, text ="Lowest")
        rbLow.pack()

        #Add FindEmployee by Amount Button
        btFindEmployee_A = Button(frame1, text = "Find Employee by Amount")
        btFindEmployee_A.pack()

        #Add WriteOutput Button
        btOutput = Button(frame1, text = "Write Output to File")
        btOutput.pack()

        #Add Cancel Button
        btCancel = Button(frame1, text = "Cancel")
        btCancel.pack()



        btReadFile.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        btShowPayroll.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        btFindEmployee.grid(row = 2, column = 4)
        rbHigh.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
        rbLow.grid(row = 3, column = 4)
        btFindEmployee_A.grid(row = 3, column = 6)
        btOutput.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
        btCancel.grid(row = 4, column = 4)



        window.mainloop()

PayrollSummary()
```

Comment: use `pack()` or `grid()`, not both on the same element(s). You can also use `pack()` to put `frame(s)` in window and `grid()` to put widgets inside frame(s).

Answer (score 0):

`pack()`, `grid()` and `place()` are three methods to put widgets in window (or in other widget).
If you use `grid()` with some widget then don't use `pack()` or `place()`.

Doc on effbot.org: [grid](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), [pack](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm), [place](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm)

I removed all `.pack()` except `frame.pack()` and get almost what you expected.

[image]

Now widgets need to be aligned to left (`'west'`) with `sticky='w'`

And after adding second `Frame` I got

[image]

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

class PayrollSummary:
    def __init__(pay):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Employee Payroll")

        #Add Frame 1
        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()

        #Add ReadFile Button
        btReadFile = Button(frame1, text = "Read File")

        #Add ShowPayroll Button
        btShowPayroll = Button(frame1, text = "Show Payroll")

        #Add FindEmployee by Name Button
        btFindEmployee = Button(frame1, text = "Find Employee by Name")

        #Add Highest Radio Button
        rbHigh = Radiobutton(frame1, text = "Highest")

        #Add Lowest Radio Button
        rbLow = Radiobutton(frame1, text ="Lowest")

        #Add FindEmployee by Amount Button
        btFindEmployee_A = Button(frame1, text = "Find Employee by Amount")

        #Add WriteOutput Button
        btOutput = Button(frame1, text = "Write Output to File")

        #Add Cancel Button
        btCancel = Button(frame1, text = "Cancel")

        btReadFile.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky='w')
        btShowPayroll.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky='w')
        btFindEmployee.grid(row = 2, column = 4, sticky='w')
        rbHigh.grid(row = 3, column = 2, sticky='w')
        rbLow.grid(row = 3, column = 4, sticky='w')
        btFindEmployee_A.grid(row = 3, column = 6, sticky='w')
        btOutput.grid(row = 4, column = 2, sticky='w')
        btCancel.grid(row = 4, column = 4, sticky='w')

        #Add Frame 2
        frame2 = Frame(window, bg='red')
        frame2.pack(fill='both') # try without `fill`

        label2 = Label(frame2, text='Label in bottom Frame', bg='green')
        label2.pack()

        window.mainloop()

PayrollSummary()
```